# How to keep command permanent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, command-line

I installed rails on my ubuntu machine, and if I want to use rails, I have to run:

source /home/dvdpk/.rvm/scripts/rvm

every single time. How do I make it so that I don't have to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the command to your .bashrc file located in your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your ~/.bashrc file

```
alias use_rails='source /home/stkim/.rvm/scripts/rvm'
```

Then you can either chose to run `use_rails` whenever you'd like to run the command, or include another line after that in ~/.bashrc that simply makes the call every time you log in:

```
alias use_rails='source /home/stkim/.rvm/scripts/rvm'
use_rails
```

For the edits to take effect, either start a new session, or `source ~/.bashrc`